# How to take into account dropout voltage of a buck converter to find minimum input voltage required?

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, buck

In DC/DC buck converters datasheet dropout voltage vs output current is given like the graph seen below. To find the worst case minimum input voltage, lets say at 3.3V output and 1A output current, to this converter i would look at the 105C line and see there will be a 1.5V dropout. Therefore if the minimum input voltage for proper operation is 5V than i have to provide a minimun of 6.5V for proper operation at the highest temperature condition. Am interpreting this correctly?

[image]

Comment: What you write is true assuming that the dropout voltage stays the same between Vout = 3.3 V (this graph) and Vout = 5 V (for which we have no data). The question is if that is a fair assumption. At higher input voltages buck converters charge the inductor faster so with a higher current. This might cause more voltage drop.

Comment: But, with higher voltages you get better turn-on characteristics from MOSFETs (if used).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the ~1.5V dropout voltage refers to the minimum difference between *actual* input and output voltage, not *nominal* input voltage and output voltage.  Thus you'll need at least \$ 1.5V + 3.3V = 4.8V \$ input voltage at 1A output current.

Similarly, if you want to run your circuit at 105C and draw 3A, you'll need at least \$2.2V + 3.3V = 5.5V \$.